# where can I download Java 8 base profile?

Tags: java, java-8

I am under the impression that with version 8, we would be able to download parts of the jdk we need and it will be full functional. I am unable to locate java 8 compact profile anywhere. (not the early access versions)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573958/how-to-create-compact-profiles

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**  try [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otncn#javase8). It only works for Java embedded.

**Long answer:** Java embedded is a version of Java with [specific modifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/se-embeddocs/index.html#faq2) for the embedded market. Profiles is one of those features. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCaBno_Euqk&feature=youtu.be) is a tutorial for java profiles

As you can see in the [power point](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2013/connect/fileDownload/session/40749B8E6513B4D4366B6D01B9C08257/CON3736_Vandette.pptx) (page 20 and 21) of this oracle [presentation](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2013/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=3736) you have two choices: a [reference implementation](https://jdk8.java.net/java-se-8-ri/) built for demostrations purposes or Java embedded.

Just to address some comments:
[Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) project was [delayed](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/project-jigsaw-delayed-until-java-9-198007) to Java 9 but part of this work made its way into Java 8 in the form of [Profiles](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/tech/compact-profiles-overview-2157132.html)

Comment: so profiles are not available for regular jdk/jre, just embedded?

Comment: It seems so. But I had not been able to post a clear link with a 100% clear response from Oracle.

Comment: Here says "So at less than one-third the original size of the *already* space-optimized Java *SE-Embedded* release"

https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/a_first_look_at_compact