# How to create compact profiles

Tags: java, java-8

I was googling to find a way to create a Compact profile in Java 1.8 .Is it possible to create a compact profile because [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/introducing_the_ejdk) is saying it is for embedded version only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer

[JEP 161](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/161) says that profiles must be in Java 8. They are. To create them, use `make profiles`

### Slightly longer answerr

Your suspicion that profiles may exist on embedded platforms only and comment from @skiwi confused me a bit and I decided to check it myself.

#### Example with OpenJDK

To check profiles existence I took OpenJDK. I built it on my ubuntu x86 (I read [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/raw-file/tip/README) and [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html) READMEs and process was simple). Instructions say finish with `make all` command. However, there were not compact profiles after that. Then I read Makefile help section and invoke `make profiles`. Success

```
$ hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
$ cd jdk8
$ bash ./get_source.sh 
$ bash ./configure 
$ make all
$ make profiles
```

Then I found 'images' directory and went there

```
$ cd build/linux-x86-normal-server-release/images/
$ export PATH=j2re-compact1-image/bin/:$PATH
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-internal-fasdaq_2014_03_22_20_17-b00, profile compact1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

As you can see from output:

1. It works
2. It's not embedded
3. It's compact1 profile
4. It's 1.8.0 version

#### About embedded and [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/introducing_the_ejdk) you provided

There is a [jrecreate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/jrecreate.htm) tool that allows you to get jre with profile/vm/extensions you want (and do not include these you don't want).

> so that applications that do not require the entire Platform can be deployed and run on small devices (c) [jep161](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/161)

There is no such tool in OpenJDK. Jrecreate is a part of embedded java as you can read from [release notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/release-notes/index.html).
It's hard question for me: what do you want to reach creating compact profile of non-embedded java. However, you're capable to do it :)