# Java Compact profile for Windows(How?)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Oracle Java Development Kit. I developed an application with JavaFx,h2Database and Jasper Studio. But My simple java program is more than 190MB if i include the jre bundle. Someone suggested to use Java Compact profile to reduce the size.

I have downloaded EJDK and tried to use jrecreate.bat on windows. But it makes the compact profile only for Linux. I don't see any files for windows.

I am also using Intellij IDE, I don't see any option in this IDE too.

How do i create Compact Profile in windows? Possible to do it in Intellij IDE? Any other way for windows? No download option of those profile?

There was an answer [How to create compact profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573958/how-to-create-compact-profiles) but i don't want to use openjdk.

Comment: You can reduce the size of the JRE by removing unneded files: See this explanation from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html

Comment: I tried. I can't package with Advanced Installer if i delete any files!

Comment: Is it safe? They i can remove java.exe too?

Comment: Depends on how you start your application. If you do have an .exe wrapper then you don't need `java.exe`

Comment: I am using Advanced Installer for packaging. It is throw errors if i delete any files from jre. Confused!

Answer (score 1):

If you are adventurous, you could use [Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) and a [Java 9 early access edition](https://jdk9.java.net/download/), which provides a [modular jre](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/), which can be [used to run JavaFX applications](https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2016/04/26/a-javafx-helloworld-using-java-9s-project-jigsaw-in-60-seconds/) requiring a minimal runtime bundle for the application.

For Java 8, you can refer to the following answer:

- [Build Custom JDK, delete useless libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966151/build-custom-jdk-delete-useless-libs/37966599#37966599)