# Build Custom JDK, delete useless libs

Tags: java, java-8

How can I delete useless libraries from my JDK and it's possible?

[image]

Comment: what does *useless libs* mean?

Comment: You can simply delete the jar files on your file system. But be aware, that some java applications may need them!

Comment: I want create custom jdk compiler for my program

Comment: I don't advise you to delete all these `.jar` files that manually without understanding what each `.jar` does. If I got you correctly, you want to assemble your own JDK without modules which you are not using. Such feature will be presented in Java 9 ([Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/)).

Comment: Java SE Embedded has [compact profiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/plat-dev-quick-start.htm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and [documented by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html).

For our project we use the following "cleanup script". Yours may be different, see comments (for instance: we do not use JavaFX).

```
#!/bin/sh
# Remove all not-needed files, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html
# Documentation
rm -f jre/README.txt
rm -f jre/THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
rm -f jre/THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
rm -f jre/Welcome.html
# optional files 
rm -f jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
rm -f jre/lib/ext/access-bridge.jar
rm -f jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-32.jar
rm -f jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
rm -f jre/bin/rmid.*
rm -f jre/bin/rmiregistry.*
rm -f jre/bin/tnameserv.*
rm -f jre/bin/keytool.*
rm -f jre/bin/kinit.*
rm -f jre/bin/klist.*
rm -f jre/bin/ktab.*
rm -f jre/bin/policytool.*
rm -f jre/bin/orbd.*
rm -f jre/bin/servertool.*
rm -f jre/bin/javaws.*
rm -f jre/lib/jfr.*
# can be deleted when private application runtime is used (like launch4j)
rm -f jre/bin/java.exe
# launch4j uses javaw.exe. So do NOT delete!
rm -f jre/bin/javacpl.exe
rm -f jre/bin/jabswitch.exe
rm -f jre/bin/java_crw_demo.dll
rm -f jre/bin/JavaAccessBridge-32.dll
rm -f jre/bin/JavaAccessBridge.dll
rm -f jre/bin/JAWTAccessBridge-32.dll
rm -f jre/bin/JAWTAccessBridge.dll
rm -f jre/bin/WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll
rm -f jre/bin/WindowsAccessBridge.dll
rm -f jre/bin/wsdetect.dll
rm -f jre/bin/deploy.dll
rm -f jre/bin/javacpl.cpl
rm -f jre/lib/deploy.jar
rm -f jre/lib/plugin.jar
rm -Rf /s /q jre/bin/dtplugin
rm -Rf /s /q jre/bin/plugin2
rm -Rf /s /q jre/lib/deploy
# JavaFX related
rm -f jre/lib/javafx.properties
rm -f jre/lib/jfxswt.jar
rm -f jre/bin/decora_sse.dll
rm -f jre/bin/fxplugins.dll
rm -f jre/bin/glass.dll
rm -f jre/bin/glib-lite.dll
rm -f jre/bin/gstreamer-lite.dll
rm -f jre/bin/javafx_font.dll
```

Windows version:

```
:: Remove all not-needed files, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html
:: Documentation
del jre\README.txt
del jre\THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
del jre\THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
del jre\Welcome.html
:: optional files 
del jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
del jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar
del jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-32.jar
del jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
del jre\bin\rmid.*
del jre\bin\rmiregistry.*
del jre\bin\tnameserv.*
del jre\bin\keytool.*
del jre\bin\kinit.*
del jre\bin\klist.*
del jre\bin\ktab.*
del jre\bin\policytool.*
del jre\bin\orbd.*
del jre\bin\servertool.*
del jre\bin\javaws.*
del jre\lib\jfr.*
:: can be deleted when private application runtime is used (like launch4j)
del jre\bin\java.exe
:: launch4j uses javaw.exe. So do NOT delete!
del jre\bin\javacpl.exe
del jre\bin\jabswitch.exe
del jre\bin\java_crw_demo.dll
del jre\bin\JavaAccessBridge-32.dll
del jre\bin\JavaAccessBridge.dll
del jre\bin\JAWTAccessBridge-32.dll
del jre\bin\JAWTAccessBridge.dll
del jre\bin\WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll
del jre\bin\WindowsAccessBridge.dll
del jre\bin\wsdetect.dll
del jre\bin\deploy.dll
del jre\bin\javacpl.cpl
del jre\lib\deploy.jar
del jre\lib\plugin.jar
rmdir /s /q jre\bin\dtplugin
rmdir /s /q jre\bin\plugin2
rmdir /s /q jre\lib\deploy
:: JavaFX related
del jre\lib\javafx.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

delete more jfx stuff:

del jre\lib\jfx*.*
del jre\bin\jfx*.*