# How to set compact profile for a JAVA project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I need to compile my java project using jdk8 compact profile 2. I did it using Netbeans. Is there any option in eclipse to set compact profile?

Comment: First you need to download java embedded. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554425/where-can-i-download-java-8-base-profile

And: 
https://www.eclipsecon.org/na2014/session/java-se-8-compact-profiles-embedded-development

Comment: Three years without an answer, did you find a way?

Comment: I do not know the current status but there a bug reported for this and it has not been closed or  marked fixed. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489980